# How can I forward texts to my  tablet and reply back?

Tags: sms, remote-control

I have a tablet running Android 4.0.1, and a cell phone running 2.2.

**When I'm working on my tablet, I would like to be able to see my texts and phone calls get forwarded to the tablet**, which doesn't have a SIM card, and be able to interact with them as if I was on my cell phone, preferably over wi-fi and/or bluetooth. Is this possible? Paid solutions are acceptable as well.

Comment: tablet doesn't have sim card means it is not capable of having a sim or it's capable but you choose not to use a sim in the tablet?

Comment: No SIM card capabilities. Or if there is, I haven't seen it, but wouldn't buy one anyways

Answer (score 6):

If you're in the USA, use [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/) - it allows a user to make voice calls while on WiFi and also allows sending / receiving SMS.

Also look at [Tablet Talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apdroid.tabtalk&hl=en) for your SMS needs at least. In early development, there's also [Phone Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyandroid.phonelink)

If you're working on your tablet, I believe the simplest solution for voice calls is to have a bluetooth handsfree paired with your phone so you can make and receive calls.

Comment: In the land of the snow and canucks... Canada can't take advantage of Google Voice yet :(

Answer (score 6):

I've tried several solutions like TabletTalk, Desksms, but none of them was really reliable. Two weeks ago I found [mysms](http://www.mysms.com) which works very similar, but for me works a lot better.

You install mysms on your phone and on your tablet (there's a seperate tablet app for this) and it immediately syncs your messages from your phone to your tablet. If you send a message from your tablet it will also be synced back to your phone. You get notifications for new messages and have a few settings to optimize them for your use.
As far as I know there's no option for forwarding calls, but for texting it's just great!

Answer (score 4):

Use [Tablet Talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apdroid.tabtalk&hl=en). I use this between my phone and tablet, and it works flawlessly. Auto syncs messages between the two, and forwards texts and calls to the tablet when connected. Has lots of settings to autoconnect, and suppress notifications on the phone when it pushes things to the tablet. I have it setup to connect whenever both my phone and tablet are connected to my home wifi network, or when the tablet is tethered to my phone. It even has a floating notification window that you can enable, so you can quickly reply to an incoming text, then get back to whatever you were doing on your tablet. Brilliant app, barely use my phone at all any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GTalkSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms). It may not be easy to configure for the average user. But if you get the idea, create some XMPP Accounts and are able to install one of the many XMPP Clients for Android on your tablet, you get exactly what you want.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into GtalkSMS. GTalkSMS is an open source GPL licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Comment: The link is showing an error page. Is this available in Canada? And I'm going to have to do research into what XMPP is

Comment: Installed but having issues. Where do I see messages?

Comment: On the XMPP client on the other side. As I said, it's not that user friendly and you have to have some technical knowledge. Please refer to the offical [How-To Setup GtalkSMS](http://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/wiki/HowToSetUp). For further assistance ask on the [users forum](http://groups.google.com/group/gtalksms-users).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your SMS off your phone to your tablet via [DeskSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.desktopsms&hl=en).  Works well, I've been using it for nearly a year now.  It'll also forward your SMS to your email and you can reply via email just as if you were texting.

Phone calls is a bit trickier without Google Voice.  The best Android app solution in Canada now that GV has closed the 403 area code hack is probably [Bud Phone](http://www.budphone.ca/), which gives you free calling within and to most Canadian cities.  If memory serves, you can forward your phone to it or it to your regular phone.  It's run by FreePhoneLine.ca, which is a pretty reliable VOIP telco.

Comment: This looks promising. Installing now, then will set up when I get home. I assume I don't need it installed on my tablet :P

Comment: SMS you don't need anything other than your email client.  For BudPhone you'd need their soft client on your phone I should think, if you want to take calls on your tablet.

Comment: The first link looks dead to me.

Comment: @Firelord: that can't be surprising after  three and a half years, buddy.

Comment: My purpose was to make you aware of the state of  your answer. Whether you update it or not is up to you entirely.

Answer (score 0):

[MAXS](http://projectmaxs.org) (Modular Android XMPP Suite) allows you to send and receive SMS messages over [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP). Using an XMPP client on your tablet you can therefore receive and reply to SMS messages from your Android smartphone.

It also allows you to control various aspects of Android, includes a SMS/Call/Battery notification and reply system. Additionaly it is able to send and receive files to and from your Android device. There are many other features too.

<sup>Note: According to the FAQ I have to disclose that I am involved into MAXS. MAXS is an open source GPLv3 licensed Android app. Everyone can contribute.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I use PushBullet in the Google Play Store. You install PushBullet on all of your devices (even Windows and Mac computers, Android Phones, IOS and they also have browser plug-ins for every browser out there.

Once installed on each device, you have to sign in with your Google credentials.

Now, when a text (or any other notification comes in such as a Facebook message or what have you), the app gives a pop-up on the computer or tablet allowing you to respond to the message, dismiss the message, mute the app, etc.

It doesn't sync your text message history onto each device, but it does allow you to receive messages on each device and respond to them. Your cell phone, of course, has to be powered on, as the messages are still being sent and received via your phone and relayed to your other devices.

If you are running a device any earlier than Android 4.4, you can't reply to messages, only receive them.

Another feature of PushBullet is that you can send files, links, photos, etc. from your PC to your device, and vice versa. It's an easy way to transfer files.

Their website is www.pushbullet.com

Comment: Has the battery usage dropped? I used PB about a year ago, and it was a battery killer, so I uninstalled it

Answer (score 0):

[MightyText](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms) works for me. Also does some other helpful things when my phone is out of reach.

Comment: Can you explain how to set this up with that app (and link it)?

Answer (score -1):

For text on your tablet, I found an app on Google Play called [TextNow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enflick.android.TextNow). It gives you "text number" in the area code you want and you can text any number (all for free and not just for "app to app" text only...). Did you find how to make and receive phone call on a tablet without a SIM card?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. I basically want my texts sent and received on my phone, and also synced with my tablet

Answer (score -1):

You could get HeyWire on your tablet, its completely free texting, they have small adds in the bottom, but you will hardly ever notice em. They give you a
new HeyWire number though. You dont have to buy it or spend any money at all, you just have to download it and install. It doesnt send your cellphones text messages to your tablet though. Ive been using it for months now. Its quick and very simple..

Answer (score -1):

Just found this forum while searching Google. Downloaded mysms onto android phone and onto tablet, enabled tethering on the phone, connected the tablet to the phones Hotspot and it works like magic.

Comment: Hi monkey, welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you please [edit] to include information about the app, link to it, etc? This answer is quite low in the quality standards we expect

Comment: There are more than one mysms app in Play Store. Consider following Luke's advice.